# RewriteRule statement is evaluated despite [L] flag on a prior one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying build an if/else branching logic which goes like this:

```
if ( <URL> corresponds to an existing file ( with the exception of those within the "server" directory ) ) {
    don't modify <URL>
}
else if ( "pages/<URL>.(html|php)" corresponds to an existing file ) {
    re-write it to that
}
else {
    re-write the URL to index.php
}
```

And here is the `.htaccess` file I came up with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^server/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ".*" "-" [L]

RewriteCond "pages/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.(html|php)" -f
RewriteRule "(.*)" "pages/%1.$1" [L]

RewriteRule ".*" "index.php" [L]
```

The issue I'm having is this:

When I visit `server/lib/router.php`, it executes that script, when instead it is supposed to execute `index.php`.

Now, I understand that the L flag in `.htaccess` triggers another iteration of the URL-rewriting logic, but I don't get how this results in the last rule being ultimately executed.

Answer (score 0):

-f parameter for RewriteCond expects a filesystem path.

The right syntax is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^server/
RewriteCond /path/to/your/server/root/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ".*" "-" [L]
```

You may have to edit the same directive on the second rule too.